# how to compute percentage of similarity between histograms (feature vector)

Tags: c#, image-processing, histogram, accord.net

I need to compare and compute similarity between local binary pattern(`LBP`) histograms of grey scale images for face recognition.

Computed histogram is in array form and used `Accord.net` to compute it.

(Histogram is `int [,][]` form and when I get a histogram using break point, i obtain `int [3,3][256]` so they are combination of `[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [1,0] ...... [2,1], [2,2]` and inside of `[,]` array, there are `256 values` from `0` to `255`)

My code for obtaining histogram is this;

```
//LBP setting is default which are;
//Cell size of the histogram is 6 pixcel
//Block size of the histogram is 3 cells
 private int [,][] histo (BitmapSource croppedImage)
 {
     var converted = BitmapFromSource(croppedImage);
     var output = LBP.ProcessImage(converted);
     var qwert = LBP.Histograms;
     { LBP.ProcessImage(converted); };

     return qwert;
 }
```

How can I get the percentage of similarity between histograms?

Could you just provide me some hint to compare them?

Additionally, I have total 48 histograms under 1 image. Is there any effective way to combine 48 histograms together for comparison with another set of 48 histograms? and any recommendation of effective library then `Accord.Net` to compute `LBP` histograms? Information and documents for `Accord.Net` is very few and it makes me harder to learn about it as I am a beginner.

Thank you for reading my post and 
I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OpenCV** is leading image processing library which provides many of widely known algorithms.It is available in CSharp .

For histogram comparison, **Chi-squared distance** is a good method. It is available in OpenCV.

For your 3rd question,concatenating histograms,you have to **normalize** concatenated histogram into [0-1] range for better comparison.

Comment: I tried to use EmguCV for my programme but it seems that it is not yet as powerful as openCV. For concatenating part, how can I proceed?? I already normalised histograms but I do not know how to concatenate them together. By the way, really thank you for your answer!!